# Zend framework Krixton_JsonRpc_Client and call method

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc

I'm trying to figure out what is going on below:

```
public function serviceAction(){
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setAuth($config['api']['username'],$config['api']['password']);

$service = new Krixton_JsonRpc_Client($config['api']['endpoint'], $client);

switch($this->_getParam('task'))
{
   case 'test':
       if(!this->getParam('newsletter_id')){
            $this->_helper->json(array('sent'=>false,'error'=>'Newsletter ID is invalid, must be numeric'));
            return;
       }

       $request = $service->call('newsletter.send', array($this->_getParam('newsletter_id'),false));
       $this->_helper->json($request->result));
   break;

}

}
```

What I'm trying to find out is how does

```
`Zend_Registry::get('config')`, $client->setAuth and $service->call`
```

works?

I understand `_getParam('task')` is a method to get get or post variables but not sure about the others. I had a look through some Zend documentations but if someone could help me out that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening there, the first one is `Zend_Registry`. `get()`allow you to get a value previously registered in the registry via `Zend_Registry::set('key', $value)`. Usually, 'config' is your application configuration, which is the **application.ini** file.

basically, you would register *config* using this bootstrap method:

```
protected function _initConfig()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    return $config;
}
```

The second ones are nothing else than methods of `Zend_Http_Client`. `setAuth()`is used to set a basic HTTP authentification, and `call()`is an internal method of your object `Krixton_JsonRpc_Client`.

If you're trying to understand deep down how does these methods work, you should read the man first (especially [Zend_registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html) and [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html) pages) and then read carefully the source code.

Answer (score 2):

`Zend_Registry::get('config')` ('config' is name of an array in this case) is recalling data that was saved to the [registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html), probably in the `Bootstrap.php` to make the information in the `application.ini`(configuration file) available everywhere.

The Bootstrap.php probably caontains something similar to:

```
protected function _initRegistry() {

        //make application.ini configuration available in registry
        $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
        Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    }
```

`$client->setAuth` is simply providing user credentials to `Zend_Http_Client()` [HTTP LINK](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) that were stored in the configuration file and accessed through the $config array.

`$service->call` I'm quite sure what this doing because I'm not familiar with the class (likely custom) being used. It looks like a request for a newsletter is being made based on 'id'.